# Set font-height to half the textblock height

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am trying to set the font-height to half the size of the TextBlock. The TextBlock is in a Grid ie. in a row of the Grid.
The grid row spans multiple rows.

I have tried.

```
Textblock t = new TextBlock();
t.LineHeight = t.ActualHeight/2;
```

But the  ActualHeight is always 0.

Comment: it depends on the time you refer to `ActualHeight`, if the code above is exactly you have, I think it of course will fail, try setting the `LineHeight` later at some appropriate time or in some event (I'm not sure, it's a long time without touching desktop application development :(

Answer (score 1):

`ActualHeight` is only calculated after the element is loaded. To get the size of the `TextBlock` before being loaded into the visual tree, you can call the `Measure()` method like this:

```
var t = new TextBlock();
var infiniteSize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

t.Text = "Something";
t.FontSize = 12;
t.Measure(infiniteSize);

t.LineHeight = t.DesiredSize.Height / 2;
```

The `infiniteSize` variable tells the `Measure()` method to give you the optimal size of the element assuming you have infinite space to draw the element.

**Alternate Solution**

You can tap into `TextBlock.SizeChanged` event and update the line-height.

```
var t = new TextBlock();

t.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
   t.LineHeight = t.ActualHeight / 2;
};
```

Comment: Didn't change the fontheight.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the sample. You need to set some text in the `TextBlock`.

Comment: It still doesn't change the lineheight. Can you show me how to do it through onload event handler? I tried onload of both the grid nd window but the desired height didn't changed and ActualHeight was still 0.

Comment: Use the `SizeChanged` event instead of `Loaded`. This way when the `Grid` changes in size, the line-height is updated.

Comment: The size is still 0 even in sizechanged event.

Comment: Well then, you have to show me what you're doing. If your grid is loaded in the visual tree, then these events should fire.